# When targeting API 26, overflow menu items become invisible

Tags: android, android-menu

I have an options menu in my app, which has more than six items, so there is a "More" item that brings up the overflow menu. The menu is posted by the default menu triggers, and a custom trigger that invokes Activity.openOptionsMenu().

The menu itself is built from this resource file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_copy"
          android:title="Copy"
          android:icon="@drawable/copy"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_paste"
          android:title="Paste"
          android:icon="@drawable/paste"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_preferences"
          android:title="Preferences"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_flip_calc_printout"
          android:title="Print-Out"
          android:icon="@drawable/printer"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_clear_printout"
          android:title="Clear Print-Out"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_about"
          android:title="About Free42"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_import"
          android:title="Import Programs"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mi_export"
          android:title="Export Programs"/>
</menu>
```

So far, so good. The menu and the Java logic that creates and posts it has worked for years, but now I'm changing the targetSdkVersion from API level 8 to 26, per the latest Play requirements, and now all of a sudden, the menu items in the overflow menu have become invisible.

The overflow menu still posts, and it still has the correct size, and the menu items still work. You just can't see them any more: the whole menu is solid black now, which is the normal background color; the menu item text is missing.

The phone on which I'm testing is a Motorola G5 running Android 8.1.0. This is the only device I have available for testing with API 26 at the moment, at least until I figure out how to create an AVD with API >= 26.

N.B. In the Android simulator with an API level 8 image, the overflow menu still looks fine. It used to look fine on the Moto G5 as well, before I targeted API 26. If I change the target back to 8, the overflow menu works again.

Any thoughts on what I could do to fix this? My Google skills aren't working on this one... Any ideas would be most welcome!

Comment: This is random, but kudos for the app. I use it all the time, it is the best calc emulator around

Comment: Add this to your main app style  <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>

Comment: And then add this <style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
     <item name="android:popupBackground">your color code</item>
</style>

Comment: @SteelToe: My pleasure. :-)

Comment: Where do these snippets go, though? My app doesn't have a style.

Comment: check this out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource

Comment: basically its in the resources directory

Comment: you should have a file that has all of the values for the styles for your app

Comment: I don't have such a file. Never needed one before, never heard of it until now. It sounds like when you target API 26, you get a default style that defines the same foreground and background colors for overflow menus, and you then have to override that style to make sure they differ, and the code you provided does that by overriding the background color. How can you be sure that that new background color won't match whatever the foreground color may be, though? Those default styles have changed in the past... the menus used to be black-on-white, now they're white-on-black...

Comment: correct, thats why I would reccomend manually overdiding those style values, so that you wont run into that issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186612/discussion-between-thomas-okken-and-steeltoe).

Comment: @SteelToe: where did you add the "<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>"? If I put it alone, outside of the <style> as you did, I get an error: 'type attribute should be defined' (I am using Studio). If I put it insdide my Theme style it compiles ok, but the original problem of Thomas persists: nothing different happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this style file as res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Free42Theme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Free42Theme.Fullscreen" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

The first is the default theme, specified by changing the android:theme attribute on the Activity from @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar to @style/Free42Theme in AndroidManifest.xml; the second is the full-screen theme, set in the Java code, by changing the setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen) call to setTheme(R.style.Free42Theme_Fullscreen).

This changes the background of the overflow menu to white, making the black item text visible, verified on my G5. Running in the simulator with Android 2.2 (API level 8), the appearance is unchanged since the background was white there from the start.

Many thanks to SteelToe for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Cool, happy to hear you figured it out