# Overflow openoptionsmenu() shows no items

Tags: android, menu

I have an activity that calls an `openOptionsMenu()` through a button. The menu has 8 items and appears at the bottom of the screen in 2 rows. The third row is not shown, called with a "More" button in the second row. My base Theme is `@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`.

Everything worked fine until Android 10 in my Note 10. Now when I press "More", the third row appears but a black menu is shown, without items. Actually, I can still click on the items, but they are not visible. It is like the letters became black. The same code works fine in Android 4.4.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Maybe showing 3 rows instead of 2, but how? Or how to force the letters to appear white?

I tried dealing with styles as was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165132/when-targeting-api-26-overflow-menu-items-become-invisible), but failed (maybe I am not knowing how to do it? What kind of item is the optionsMenu to be called @styles?).

I can also open a long vertical menu at the left, but I don't know how to place the menu.